# Regex match match "words" that contain two continuous streaks of digits and letters or vice-versa and split them

Tags: python, regex, list

I am having following line of text as given below:

```
text= 'Cms12345678 Gleandaleacademy Fee Collection 00001234Abcd Renewal 123Acgf456789'
```

I am trying to split `numbers followed by characters` or `characters followed by numbers` only to get the output as:

```
output_text = 'Cms 12345678 Gleandaleacademy Fee Collection 00001234 Abcd Renewal 123Acgf456789
```

I have tried the following approcah:

```
import re
text = 'Cms12345678 Gleandaleacademy Fee Collection 00001234Abcd Renewal 123Acgf456789'
text = text.lower().strip()
text = text.split(' ')
output_text =[]
for i in text:
    if bool(re.match(r'[a-z]+\d+|\d+\w+',i, re.IGNORECASE))==True:
        out_split = re.split('(\d+)',i)
        for j in out_split:
            output_text.append(j)
    else:
        output_text.append(i)
output_text = ' '.join(output_text)
```

Which is giving output as:

```
output_text = 'cms 12345678 gleandaleacademy fee collection 00001234 abcd renewal 123 acgf 456789 '
```

This code is also splliting the last element of text `123acgf456789` due to incorrect regex in `re.match`.
Please help me out to get correct output.

Comment: `re.sub(r'(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=[A-Za-z])', ' ', text)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew but this is giving wrong output spaces in `402ecfev845410001` term. My expected output is `Cms 1291682971 Gleandaleacademy Fee Collection 0000548 Andb Renewal 402Ecfev845410001`

Comment: Just in case, try `re.sub(r'\b(([^\W\d_]+)|\d+)((?(2)\d+|[^\W\d_]+))\b', r'\1 \3', text)`. Or `re.sub(r'\b(?:([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)|(\d+)([a-zA-Z]+))\b', r'\1\3 \2\4', text)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the second regex worked for me Thanks. But what does `r'\1\3 \2\4'` means.

Comment: `\1` etc. are [replacement backreferences](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.sub(r'\b(?:([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)|(\d+)([a-zA-Z]+))\b', r'\1\3 \2\4', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DAogZv/3)

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group (necessary for the word boundaries to be applied to all the alternatives):

  - `([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more letters and Group 2: one or more digits
  - `|` - or
  - `(\d+)([a-zA-Z]+)` - Group 3: one or more digits and Group 4: one or more letters
- `)` - end of the group
- `\b` - word boundary

During the replacement, either `\1` and `\2` or `\3` and `\4` [replacement backreferences](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) are initialized, so concatenating them as `\1\3` and `\2\4` yields the right results.

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Pmc01G):

```py
import re
text = "Cms1291682971 Gleandaleacademy Fee Collecti 0000548Andb Renewal 402Ecfev845410001"
print( re.sub(r'\b(?:([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)|(\d+)([a-zA-Z]+))\b', r'\1\3 \2\4', text) )
# => Cms 1291682971 Gleandaleacademy Fee Collecti 0000548 Andb Renewal 402Ecfev845410001
```